# How do I make a link stay a color when on the current page?

Tags: hyperlink, current-page

I'm not sure if this is done with javascript or css but if there is anyone out there who can be of any help....please, I sincerely appreciate it! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you mean something like "I want visited links and unvisited links to render as the same color?" If so, look at "a:visited", implementation of a CSS pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by applying CSS to the different `a` tag states.  This resource should be helpful:

http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm

Comment: Yeah, I seen this before. The site only displays hover, active, etc. but nothing for current...

Comment: So what you want is to have any links that point to the current page marked in a specific color?  If so I think you'd have to use a bit of JavaScript for that one.